# Is there a resource showing all the J3 classes mapped to the J4 equivalents?

Tags: joomla-4

I know we are using

`Factory` instead of `JFactory`

I would like to know if there is an easy way to know the mapping.

I'd also like to understand if any have been deprecated or replaced.  Is there a good resource for this?

Comment: `ROOT/libraries/classmap.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the equivalent of Joomla! classes here:

- https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.0-dev/libraries/classmap.php

Your IDE will show when a method is deprecated in your code if you set as dependency the Joomla 4.0 git directory cloned locally.

- https://docs.joomla.org/Setting_up_your_workstation_for_Joomla_development#Installing_an_IDE_.2F_Editor_.28and_debugging.29